# REALLY strange error on c++ code. Parameter being copied with a trash value and not the one i wanted

Tags: c++, parameters, parameter-passing

I don't think i could explain how pissed I am because i can't find where i missed here..

Images can explain everything:

Debug screenshot, with nxxx value (used to call it n, but that crappy variable doesn't deserve such a cool name). Breakpoint was on first line of this method.

http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/5057/value.png

The code where the method is called, `getA` and `getB` are working.. EVERYTHING was working like 10 mins ago..

First comment is the method signature, second comment is the original code, which SHOULD work. (replaced `n` variable with `0` to see if it would change anything.. turned out it didn't)

```
/*
    void HASAntData::init(float** A, 
        float** B, 
        int nxxx, 
        int R, 
        float q,
        float Q, 
        float q1, 
        float q2, 
        int S, 
        int maxrounds, 
        int nThreads, 
        int seed)
    */

    data->init( qap->getA(), 
                qap->getB(), 
                0, 
                1, 
                2, 
                3, 
                4, 
                5, 
                6, 
                7, 
                8, 
                9);

    /*
    data->init( qap->getA(), 
                qap->getB(), 
                0, 
                cudahas_R, 
                cudahas_q, 
                cudahas_Q, 
                cudahas_q1, 
                cudahas_q2, 
                cudahas_S, 
                cudahas_max_rounds, 
                cudahas_m, 
                Tools::randomInt(0, INT_MAX));
                */
```

edit:

Here's the table with all variable values, the crossed one doesn't matter for this problem.
See how some variables are OK, and some aren't

http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/6224/valuestable.png

Comment: If "EVERYTHING was working like 10 minutes ago," why don't you `Ctrl+Z` a few times and see what all you changed?

Comment: For future reference, don't take a screenshot of your code and embed the image in your question, especially since you can just copy and paste the code/data. It is easily formatted by indenting each line with 4 spaces (use Ctrl+K to do that quickly). Also, by embedding images instead of the actual text you preclude lots of people who would be willing to try out your code but can't because they can't copy/paste it.

Comment: @James McNellis, because i changed some stuff. yesterday i passed all those arguments to the constructor, now i changed it and i'm passing everything to the init method.

Comment: "used to call it n, but that crappy variable doesn't deserve such a cool name" - That's not a cool name at all. I'm sorry to say that it's a horrible parameter name. I don't know what the heck `A`, `B`, `nxxx`, `R`, `q`, `Q`, `q1`, `q2`, and `S` are supposed to mean or represent, even within the context of your code. You have to give your variables/parameters better and more meaningful names.

Comment: @In silico, i know it's not understandable, but it won't be open source, it's just a small test code, and those names were set by the author of the paper i'm implementing. want his e-mail? And the names really won't make a difference, why won't the third argument stay with it's value?

Comment: @polar: It doesn't matter if it's open source or closed source - it must be at least somewhat readable by people other than yourself. I would tell whoever set the names to come up with better names, for the sake of readability (No, do not give me his e-mail. That's your problem).

Comment: @polar: That issue aside, what do you mean it "won't stay with its value"? Variable data doesn't just change for no reason. Are you saying that when you call the function, passing `0` for the third argument, your function gets `8288160` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all the values have shifted (Q is 2 instead of 3, q1 is 3 instead of 4, R is 0 instead of 1). Where an int is interpreted as float, weird values are expected.

I guess `nxxx` must be seeing the value meant for `B`.

Is there some mismatch between the definition and declaration of `init`?

Comment: I would suggest that polar try to completely clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: here's the implementation `void HASAntData::init(float** A, float** B, int nxxx, int R, float q, float Q, float q1, float q2, int S, int maxrounds, int nThreads, int seed)`  and the definition `void init(float**, float**, int, int, float, float, float, float, int, int, int, int);`. Gonna try explicit casting these test values.

Comment: @In silico, I'm gonna remake that method tomorrow, maybe moving everything to the constructor and removing the init method.

Comment: casting won't work, actually. but yes doing a clean build might help. can you inspect the value for B and make sure it is really what is returned by `getB`? or whether it is what is returned by `getA`.

Comment: `getA` and `getB` are returning pointer values, not some small values like the other arguments, so they are probably working now (they always worked). I'm gonna try remaking and reorganizing the code tomorrow, i'll post an update later. Got to sleep asap.

Answer (score 0):

Using an optimized build? If so, that can confuse the debugger.

Otherwise, use AppVerifier to look for typical memory corruptions.

Comment: No, i didn't change a thing in the project's properties/options. And it's not just a debugger problem. I use the `n` variable to allocate space on my GPGPU, and because that variable can reach some nasty values, i get "Out of memory exception".

Comment: @polar, I didn't say you changed the properties, but rather suggested you check the current build you're debugging, and see if it has optimization turned on.